# TweetInvi SearchV2 PageSize / MaxResults param not working as expected (Twitter API)

Tags: twitter, parameters, tweetinvi

I have two near idential SearchV2 requests - however the PageSize param is working for the first, but not the second.

I tried setting the param to 'PageSize = 1' however it errors that 'MaxResults must be between 10 and...'

I'm stumped as to why it's only working for one and not the other where the only difference is the query.

**My understanding:** I thought that this would get a maximum of 10 tweets, and for each tweet, get a maxium of 10 tweets from the conversation id .. max 110 tweets in total. However I just discovered this doesn't work when KamalaHarris returned 10 tweets with 15000+ replies to the conversation id.

```
var tweets = await appClient.SearchV2.SearchTweetsAsync(new SearchTweetsV2Parameters($"from:{handle}")
            {
                PageSize = 10,
                Expansions =
                {
                TweetResponseFields.Expansions.AuthorId,
                TweetResponseFields.Expansions.ReferencedTweetsId,
                }
            });

           var postData = new List<Postdata> { };

            foreach (var tweet in tweets.Tweets)
            {
                var replies = await appClient.SearchV2.SearchTweetsAsync(new SearchTweetsV2Parameters($"conversation_id:{tweet.ConversationId}")
                {
                    PageSize = 10,
                    Expansions =
                    {
                        TweetResponseFields.Expansions.AuthorId,
                        TweetResponseFields.Expansions.ReferencedTweetsId,
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was reading totalComments from the original tweet rather than the amount of tweets gathered through the second request. Entirely my idiocy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).